# Як у слові "зміюка" виокремити суфікс

Tags: словотворення, суфікси

Як у слові "зміюка" виокремити суфікс суб'єктивної оцінки? Якщо корінь **змій**, то виходить, що суфікс **ук**, проте в одній статті натрапила на **юк**.

> Суфікс -юк- має досить широку гаму негативних відтінків: назвам предметів він
>   надає значення збільшення розміру, обсягу, якості (холодюка, калюка, грязюка, шаблюка,каменюка, закорюка), назвам осіб, тварин — значення зневажливості, презирства, інколи лайливого відтінку: зміюка, звірюка, свинюка, сатанюка, тварюка тощо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суфікс насправді **-ук**, та коли слово записане в чинному правописі, графічно виокремити цей суфікс досить складно. В таких випадках на пригоді стає практична транскрипція кирилкою, чи просто МФА:

Практична транскрипція:

> [*зміj-'ук-а*] / [*змій-'ук-а*]

МФА:

> /zmij-'uk-a/